# PHP With Command Line

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have installed WAMP in my system and have default configuration of WAMP and Its working fine. Now I want to execute a script from CLI. I have tried a lot but still failure.
I am attaching image to make clear the issue,[image]

and in System Path veriable is

***C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0***

which looks like

[image: System Path Varible]

Now i want to execute a simple script like hello-world.php,Please help me.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I don' tknow what version of php you have with your wamp installation, but based on my one, try executing it thus:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe hello-world.php
```

Comment: I  have tried but getting error that php5.3.5 os not recognised as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file,
My Version is 5.3.5

Comment: Oops, silly me! Try my edited command, substituting your 5.3.5 for my 5.4.3

Comment: Now I am getting error like,
Could not open input file:hello-world.php

Comment: You will either need to put your file hello-world.php in the folder C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5 or you will have to give the full path to where the hello-world.php file is. For example: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php.exe C:\wamp\www\hello-world.php You do know how computers work don't you?

Comment: So this is where you "accept" the answer (putting the tick on it :-)

Comment: Yes, I think Tag of usefull Answer is only when its beneficial to someone,really thanks for help :)

Comment: So answering your question was not useful? So why did you bother asking it?

Answer (score 0):

Put your PHP bin folder to the Path variable.

*C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\wamp\php;*

The Path to the folder where you can find the **php.exe**. 
After that restart the command line.

Then you can run `php` from the command line.

```
php hello-world.php
```

Comment: Can you explain more in easy step because I have little interection with CLI .
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

did you try `php hello-world.php` ?